# while converting column to row not able to fetch value from another table automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

```
select *
from (
  select vtid, convert(date, dtime) as Date from Transaction_tbl where locid = 5
) as vt
pivot (
  count(vtid)
  for vtid in (select vtid from VType_tbl)
) as pvt
```

while executing this query am getting error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'." and Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'.

actually I have one more table,name= Vtype_table  , How Can I load all vtid from vtype table in this query? I want to get output depend upon vtid.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PIVOT syntax is correct except you are using a SELECT statement inside your PIVOT.

You cannot use a SELECT statement inside the PIVOT IN clause to select column headers.  It is required that the columns for the IN clause be known prior to executing the query.

If you are looking to generate a dynamic list of `vtid` values, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to get the result and the syntax will be similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(vtid) 
                    from VType_tbl
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Date, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select vtid, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
                from Transaction_tbl 
                where locid = 5 
            ) d
            pivot 
            (
                count(vtid)
                for vtid in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Edit, if you want the type names to appear then you should be able to use the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(vt_name) 
                    from VType_tbl
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Date, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select v.vt_name, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
                from Transaction_tbl t
                inner join VType_tbl v
                  on t.vtid = v.vtid
                where locid = 5 
            ) d
            pivot 
            (
                count(vt_name)
                for vt_name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Note: I am guessing on the column name for `VType_tbl`

Comment: If you are building a pivot table with a cte earlier.` cte3 AS (select ... )` then you have the defined above logic with the `@cols` and `@query` ... there is an error. `Invalid object name 'cte3'.` how do you fix that.

Comment: @Elizabeth You should post a question. It'd be far too difficult to debug your code in comments.